# "To get + adjective" vs "to become + adjective"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Do the following sentences mean the same?

1. I was becoming fat.
2. I was starting to get fat.
3. I was getting fat.

Answer (score 0):

Yes (haha):

- I was becoming fat, so I started eating a low GI diet.
- I was starting to get skinny, because I've been eating a low GI diet.
- I was getting healthy because of my low GI diet.